# How to generate ChangelogFile by comparing two existing changelog files in Liquibase

Tags: liquibase

I went through existing posts but did not find an answer. Also most of them are almost an year old. Has this functionality been added in later releases? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Your research is correct. That functionality does not exist, and has not been added.